# Regex to match exact word without spaces

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-negation

I have a query such as the below:

```
SELECT * from table_name where lastname regexp "[[:<:]]Smith[[:>:]]"
```

This returns

- `De Smith`
- `Smith`

I only need to retrieve `Smith`

I even tried the below

```
SELECT * from surnames where last_name regexp "[[:<:]][^\s]Smith[[:>:]]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaking your requirement, but if you want to exactly match a last name then you can just use the equals operator:

```
SELECT * from table_name where TRIM(lastname) = 'Smith'
```

I used `TRIM()` on the `lastname` field just in case there might be leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This actually returns  a null value

Comment: Can you update your question by showing us what the real data looks like?